# Xcode lldb not storing properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, lldb

I am currently using Xcode 6.3.1. In the debug area, I pause the app and store a property like  `p NSString * $test = @"word"`   in the debug window. If I type `po $test` the output would be `word`, this is perfect but as soon as I let the app run. When I pause it again out of scope of the class/method it seems that they property is nil. When I type `p $test` my output would be `(NSString *) $test =`.

Is this a bug with this version of Xcode or can it be fixed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you're making an NSString and setting the lldb convenience variable to point to it.  But the runtime doesn't know that this variable is holding onto a reference to it.  So at some point ARC is going to release the actual object.

We don't retain/release lldb convenience variables in lldb.  It would be too easy to end up adding extraneous retains just because you happened to refer to something in an expression, which would change your program's behavior in a non-obvious way.

If you want an ObjC object you've created with the expression parser to persist, you can just call "objc_retain" on it.

Comment: This also seems to happen with other object, even when declared in other classes. As an example, in the main ViewController I have a "UIButton * button" with an instance of a button in it, and I store it in lldb as  "p UIButton * $btn = self.button" as soon as I leave that class in my debugger it also clears out. I am currently loading Xcode on another Mac to see if its just an issues with my system. I'll comment again on the results.

Comment: Thanks...  I'm not necessarily surprised by this.  lldb's convenience variables don't capture references to objects or try to keep them alive longer than they would in the program.  That is by design.  So if that object was going to go out of scope in the course of things, the fact that you have an lldb convenience variable pointing at it won't change that.

Comment: I used an older version of Xcode and it works fine, but as soon as I updated to 6.3.1 it has the issue. If I can't use lldb, is there an alternative to watching an object instance outside the scope of where I am currently debugging? Like if I have a class that checking network status and my debugger is in a thread. How can I get the status from that object?

Comment: I would have to know more about what is going on.  The convenience variable holds the address of your object.  It doesn't try to keep it alive, but on the other hand if that object stays alive for other reasons, its pointer should stay good, and calling methods on it later on should also work.

Comment: If you make a Single View Application and put this in the ViewController .m file you will see the issue. Add the brake  points where indicated.

Comment: If you make a Single View Application and add (at symbols removed):
interface ViewController ()
{
    UIButton * testButton;
}
end

implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     testButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    // <- (Add breakpoint) type in lldb: "p UIButton * $btn = testButton"
    // <- (Add breakpoint) type in lldb: "p $btn"     result: "(UIButton *) $btn = 0x00007f9fb9e0de90"
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // <- (Add breakpoint) type in lldb: "p $btn"      result: "(UIButton *) $btn = "
}

Comment: Yup, that's a bug.  It works when the persistent variable is a scalar, but fails when its value is a pointer to memory in the debugee.  I already filed it with http://bugreporter.apple.com.  If you want to track the bug you can file it yourself and I'll dup the one I filed to it.  Thanks for working up the example.

Comment: Thanks Jim. At least I know all we can do is wait. :)

Comment: The virtue of filing a bug would be that you would get informed about what release the bug was fixed in.